# Protobuf not generating correct imports when using java_multiple_files in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

With `example.proto` below:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package pack;

option java_package = "pack";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message TestEvent {
    int32 id = 1;

}
```

And generating it with Protoc, some classes are generated:

- Example.java
- TestEvent.java
- TestEventOrBuilder.java

The problem is that the auto-generated TestEvent class doesn't compile.  It's class declaration is generated as

```java
public final class TestEvent extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 implements TestEventOrBuilder { 
    //... Auto-generated class
}
```

But `TestEevent` doesn't import `TestEventOrBuilder`, that's the reason it doesn't compile (The problem is a simple `cannot resolve symbol TestEventOrBuilder`), accoring to Intellij. When trying to solve it's own way, `Intellij IDEA` changes the class to

```
public final class TestEvent extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 implements pack.TestEventOrBuilder
```

Is this a known issue with `Protobuf` and Intellij? How to fix the auto-compilation to understand `TestEventOrBuilder`?

Comment: Show us the compilation error, and how you compile these.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As specified, the Compilation Error was due to the class not being imported. I'm compiling these through Protobuf. It doesn't have too much to do with Java coding

Comment: More information on ProtocolBuffer can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial).

Comment: How are you trying to compile the classes? As far as I know, `protoc` only generates source.

Comment: Yeah, this works fine for me with `libprotoc 3.4.0`. Show us the steps you took to compile those classes.

Comment: (`TestEventOrBuilder` is in the same package as those other classes. It doesn't require an `import` statement.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added to the question. Intellij auto-compiles the code, and also gives me options on how to resolve it, but I shouldn't change generated classes

Comment: Apparently it's an issue with Intellij, it works fine in eclipse. I'll edit the question to add this information.